# Android - Trigger MainActivity to do something from custom View

Tags: android, view, kotlin

I would like to let my `MainActivity` know that there is something to do (e.g. calculate stuff) from a custom `View`. The `View` detects user inputs through touch and the MainActivity has to update certain user controls with a calculation from those `View`-Values. Basically I did an override on `onTouchEvent`:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    val x = event?.x
    val y = event?.y

    val dX = x?.minus(prevX)
    val dY = y?.minus(prevY)
    if(dX!! > 0){
        lowerBound = x.toInt()
    } else{
        upperBound = x.toInt()
    }

    prevX = x!!.toInt()
    prevY = y!!.toInt()
    this.invalidate() //tell view to redraw
    return true
}
```

How can I let `MainActivity`know that `lowerBound` and `upperBound` updated?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but starting a new activity directly from your view is probably not the best approach. The first thing that I can think about - you can create a listener and pass it from holding activity to your view. And afterwards just pass needed values through your intent to another activity.

Comment: I don't want to start a new activity, I just want to let the current MainUI Acitivty know that it has to calculate stuff and update UI-controls.

Comment: So what is bad about defining a listener?

Comment: I didn't know about a listener until now - I will have a look at it.

Comment: I think you can simply keep your bounds as field in activity and define a private method `onBoundsUpdated(upperBound,lowerBound)` in activity
and compare bounds with fields if they have changed or not and do what ever you want to do with your activity.

Answer (score 0):

As already recommended in the comments I'll go a little bit deeper in "hot to use a listener".

First of all, a "Listener" is nothing more than a `interface` which get called if something happen elsewhere. The best example is the [`View.setOnClickListener(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).

How to use that in your case?

Simply define a `interface` (best location is here inside your custom View):

```
interface OnBoundsUpdatedListener {
  fun onBoundsUpdated(upperBound: Int, lowerBound: Int)
}
```

Then you have to create a property in your `CustomView` and call the Listener if the bounds have changed :

```
// Constructor and stuff
val onBoundsUpdateListener: OnBoundsUpdatedListener? = null


override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
...
onBoundsUpdateListener?.onBoundsUpdated(upperBound, lowerBound)
...
}
```

In your `Activtiy` you can find that View and set the listener:

```
val myCustomView = findViewById<MyCustomView>(R.id.id_of_your_customview)
myCustomView.onBoundsUpdateListener = object : OnBoundsUpdatedListener {
    override fun onBoundsUpdated(upperBound, lowerBound) {
       // Get called if its called in your CustomView
    }
}
```

> Note: The code can be simplified. But that is the basic stuff